# What's the difference between a Chef server, workstation, client, and node?

Tags: chef-infra

I'm having a hard time differentiating between a Chef `server`, `workstation`, `client`, and `node`. More importantly, what's their positions when setting up an initial environment? I've read countless articles and documentations, but I can't seem to understand the different roles and how they play in a completely automated setting. That is, when everything is up and running, how does one update the cookbooks and sync up all the chef managed servers?

I currently have a Chef server setup (on Ubuntu) that successfully running `chef-server-webui`. Do I need to use my computer as a workstation to setup the repository cookbooks, or do I need another dedicated workstation that will house the repository?

Lastly, if I want to bootstrap instances, what do I need to install on those instances? Do I need to setup chef/knife or something else?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, that's the [documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/) in short.

- A [node](http://docs.opscode.com/chef_overview_nodes.html) is any server or virtual server that is configured to be maintained by a chef-client. A node can be physical or cloud-based. A Chef organization comprises any combination of physical and cloud-based nodes. A chef-client runs on each node. Ohai is used to collect data about the system so that it is available to the chef-client during every Chef run.
- [Workstation](http://docs.opscode.com/chef_overview_workstation.html): A workstation is a computer that is configured to run Knife, to synchronize with the Chef repository, and interact with a single Chef Server. The workstation is the location from which most users of Chef will do most of their work..
- The [Chef Server](http://docs.opscode.com/chef_overview_server.html) acts as a hub for configuration data. The Chef Server stores cookbooks, the policies that are applied to cookbooks, and metadata that describes each registered node in the infrastructure. Nodes use the chef-client to ask the Chef Server for configuration details, such as recipes, templates, and file distributions. The chef-client then does as much of the configuration work as possible on the nodes themselves (and not on the Chef Server). This scalable approach distributes the configuration effort throughout the organization.

> when everything is up and running, how does one update the cookbooks and sync up all the chef managed servers?

You have your cookbooks checked out locally on your PC. After changing them, you upload them to the chef-server using `knife` (or [`berks`](http://berkshelf.com)) and commit the changes to the Git repo (to have a history of your changes).

> Do I need to use my computer as a workstation to setup the repository cookbooks, or do I need another dedicated workstation that will house the repository?

Yes, create an [admin user](https://docs.chef.io/server_orgs.html#server-admins) for yourself, which is used by `knife` on your PC (the workstation) to talk to the server. Knife is the admin tool for chef, so you will install it only on workstations. To login into the web interface, you use your *user* credentials.
(the opposite of `knife` is `chef-client`, which downloads the cookbooks and executes them (and configures the node)).

> if I want to bootstrap instances, what do I need to install on those instances? Do I need to setup chef/knife or something else?

The bootstrapping process installs the `chef-client` on the target node, copies the validator file, which allows the client to register at the chef-server and then starts the first run.

Comment: Do I need to install knife on my chef server? The docs are saying to run `knife configure --initial` but when I installed `chef-server` it didn't install that too.

Comment: Nope,`knife` is AFAIK a client-only tool. I think `knife configure` configures your workstation.

Comment: @StephenKing would it be bad practice to use a small server like say an aws micro instance as a workstation?

Comment: @WhyAyala You are developing cookbooks like you developing code. There are people that like using `vi` over SSH, but I wouldn't recommend that. Install ChefDK locally. The only remote system that executes `knife` commands would be a [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server that uploads coobkooks, databags etc. after checkin to VCS.

Comment: What is a client ? On my workstation I can get 2 lists, knife node list and knife client list. could you please tell the difference between these 2 list.

Comment: Please ask as a separate question and not as a comment.